# How to convert sensor SPI/I2C output to serial (RS-232)?

Tags: temperature, rs232, gps, arduino, sensors

I have a home automation project which requires me to connect small, temperature/GPS sensor boards (normally used in Arduino/Pico project and output to SPI/I2C) to an industrial controller which uses serial (RS-232) communications. Any suggestions on how to get from SPI/I2C to RS-232?
Thanks,
NuevoZeeland

Comment: I think there's an IoT Stack Exchange or something, that could be more appropriate. // Simply put, get an Arduino and make it do the job. PC serial ports are for point-to-point connections. I2C and SPI are buses.

Comment: What controller do you have that supports RS-232 only and not SPI or I²C? Possible solution: Use an additional controller that supports both the interfaces as a gateway and find or write some gateway software.